# SOLR - Block Join Parent Query parser variation possibility

Tags: search, solr, lucene, nested-documents

I recently changed the schema of our **Solr cluster** and now indexing documents in the **nested structure**. I have indexed *restaurant* as *parent* with its *dish* as *child* docs. **BJQ** (Block Join Query) parent query parser is handy to filter out all the parents for the child satisfying a given condition -

```
{!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}doc_type:dish AND dish_name:burger
```

So the above query returns all the restaurant having **burger** as one of the dish. I have a use case where I want to filter out all the restaurant having multiple dishes all at once e.g restaurant selling **burger** & **fries** both.

```
{!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}doc_type:dish AND (dish_name:burger OR dish_name:fries)
```

above query will return restaurants selling either of **burger** or **fries**.

Its seems tedious to filter out restaurants selling both using BJQ. How can I write query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

An approach I'v found uses `{!bool}`

```
q={!bool
 must="{!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}(+doc_type:dish +dish_name:burger)" 
 must="{!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}(+doc_type:dish +dish_name:fries)"
}
```

If you want to use [multivalue references](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/other-parsers.html#boolean-query-parser), please note that this does not work correctly in case of block join.

Use single value references as workaround

```
q={!bool must=$ref1 must=$ref2}
&ref1={!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}+doc_type:dish +dish_name:burger
&ref2={!parent which=doc_type:restaurant}+doc_type:dish +dish_name:fries
```